# How to change the iPhone's audio output back to non-bluetooth? (internal speakers)

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, bluetooth

At first I thought Pokemon Go is the only issue, but today I installed Clash of Clans and it is the same situation: the game audio will try to go out through the Bluetooth channel but since there is no bluetooth device around, it is all mute.

If I plug in the earbuds, then I can hear something for both Pokemon Go and Clash of Clans. The other way is: if I find and turn on a portable Bluetooth speaker, or if I go to the car and use the bluetooth there.

But there should be a way to make these app go out through the iPhone's internal speakers. How can it be done? (if I turn off Bluetooth on the iPhone, it doesn't solve the problem).

P.S. the iPhone Music app doesn't have this problem. Only the apps do -- so I don't think it is apps' problem. I am using iOS 10.2.1 which is quite recent.

P.P.S. just as a test, I just installed Angry Birds Rio, and it is exactly the same with Pokemon Go, Clash of Clans: no audio. So I don't think it is the apps' problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a guess based on an *assumption* I am making (dangerous, I know).

My assumption is that when you're playing games such as Angry Birds Rio that the audio is **not** actually outputting via Bluetooth at all.

Instead, I think the reason you **do** hear it when switching on a Bluetooth speaker is because at that point the iPhone starts outputting via Bluetooth. Prior to that, I think your iPhone **is** outputting via the iPhone's internal speakers but you're not hearing it because the volume level is not up for games.

What I mean is that iPhones have multiple volume levels. For example, it is possible to have the ringer volume level all the way up while having the games audio level all the way down.

As a test, I would start playing one of the games and make sure the volume is turned up (and also that the mute switch is not on). If that solves the problem, great! If not, report back so I or others can dig deeper.

Comment: Actually, this problem has been there for at least four months.  My phone does ring, and the songs do play.  So volume shouldn't be 0

Comment: Yes, but there are multiple volume levels. The volume level for your ringer is separate to that for games. So, for example, it may be 0 (or muted) for games while high for your ringer. Like I said, it's only a _guess_ and it's a simple test to check either way, but one worth doing just to be sure.

Comment: how do you set the volume individually for songs, ringer, and games? (games are newly installed, so it shouldn't be 0 level for volume if it is part of game's settings)

Comment: For games you just launch a game and start playing it and put the volume up. As for the ringer, you can actually just do that from the Home screen or within the Phone app. For videos you can do while playing a video. And so on.

Comment: Just to clarify what I am saying - let's say you're playing a video and you put the volume right down. You then forget about it and play another video a week later. The volume will still be down because it hasn't been turned up again since the last time a video was played. It's the same for games. Play game A and you turn the volume down and later you play game B and the volume will be the same (unless you've overridden it with app-specific settings).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally tracked down the reason. It is due to iPhone and iOS having this "semi-mute" mechanism.

So if you slide that mute button at the side of the phone at some point in the past, it is "semi-mute".  The alarm clock will still sound, the counter down timer will sound, YouTube will sound, Music app will sound, Video app (TV app) will sound, Facebook videos and live broadcast will sound, ***but games will not sound.***

Why this exception, I am not so sure. Why should YouTube and Music app both give sound but when I switch to and run my favorite game, it should not give sound, I am not so sure.